# How to apply triplet loss function in resnet50 for the purpose of deepranking

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I try to create image embeddings for the purpose of deep ranking using a triplet loss function. The idea is that we can take a pretrained CNN (e.g. resnet50 or vgg16), remove the FC layers and add an L2 normalization function to retrieve unit vectors which can then be compared via a distance metric (e.g. cosine similarity). As far as I understand the predicted vectors that come out of a pretrained CNN are not optimal, but are a good start. By adding the triplet loss function we can re-train the network to keep similar pictures 'close' to each other and different pictures 'far' apart in the feature space. Inspired by this [notebook](https://github.com/KinWaiCheuk/Triplet-net-keras/blob/master/Triplet%20NN%20Test%20on%20MNIST.ipynb)  , I tried to setup the following code, but I get an error `ValueError: The name "conv1_pad" is used 3 times in the model. All layer names should be unique.`.

```
# Anchor, Positive and Negative are numpy arrays of size (200, 256, 256, 3), same for the test images

pic_size=256
def shared_dnn(inp):
    base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(3, pic_size, pic_size), 
                          input_tensor=inp)
    x = base_model.output
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x,axis=1))(x)
    for layer in base_model.layers[15:]:
        layer.trainable = False
    return x

anchor_input = Input((3, pic_size,pic_size ), name='anchor_input')
positive_input = Input((3, pic_size,pic_size ), name='positive_input')
negative_input = Input((3, pic_size,pic_size ), name='negative_input')

encoded_anchor = shared_dnn(anchor_input)
encoded_positive = shared_dnn(positive_input)
encoded_negative = shared_dnn(negative_input)

merged_vector = concatenate([encoded_anchor, encoded_positive, encoded_negative], axis=-1, name='merged_layer')

model = Model(inputs=[anchor_input,positive_input, negative_input], outputs=merged_vector)

#ValueError: The name "conv1_pad" is used 3 times in the model. All layer names should be unique.
model.compile(loss=triplet_loss, optimizer=adam_optim)

model.fit([Anchor,Positive,Negative],
          y=Y_dummy,
          validation_data=([Anchor_test,Positive_test,Negative_test],Y_dummy2), batch_size=512, epochs=500)
```

I am new to keras and I am not quite sure how to solve this. The author in the link above creates his own CNN from scratch, but I would like to build it upon resnet (or vgg16). How can I configure `ResNet50` to use a triplet loss function (in the link above you find also the source code for the triplet loss function).

Comment: You got an answer? I have exactly the same work to do. Re-Train the Resnet with Triplet loss so that you can compare the embeddings/latent representations of image later using `ANN` or `LSH`.

Comment: @Deshwal, No not yet. I didn't follow up on this issue, but still curious what would be the solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

In your ResNet50 definition, you've written

```
base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(3, pic_size, pic_size), input_tensor=inp)
```

Remove the input_tensor argument. Change input_shape=inp.
If you're using TF backend as you mentioned the input should be (256, 256, 3), then your input should be (pic_size, pic_size, 3).

```
def shared_dnn(inp):
    base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=inp)
    x = base_model.output
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x,axis=1))(x)
    for layer in base_model.layers[15:]:
        layer.trainable = False
    return x

img_shape=(256, 256, 3)
anchor_input = Input(img_shape, name='anchor_input')
positive_input = Input(img_shape, name='positive_input')
negative_input = Input(img_shape, name='negative_input')

encoded_anchor = shared_dnn(anchor_input)
encoded_positive = shared_dnn(positive_input)
encoded_negative = shared_dnn(negative_input)

merged_vector = concatenate([encoded_anchor, encoded_positive, encoded_negative], axis=-1, name='merged_layer')

model = Model(inputs=[anchor_input,positive_input, negative_input], outputs=merged_vector)
model.compile(loss=triplet_loss, optimizer=adam_optim)

model.fit([Anchor,Positive,Negative],
          y=Y_dummy,
          validation_data=([Anchor_test,Positive_test,Negative_test],Y_dummy2), batch_size=512, epochs=500)
```

The model plot is as follows:
[model_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTbEI.png)

Comment: Thanks for your input. But keras refuses to instantiate resnet50 3 times inside the same model. that's the root of the problem. I need to find a way to tell keras that it needs to share the parameters. The original author of this code created 3 separate CNN, but as far as I can see from the literature, one should share the same CNN for this kind of problem. Why should the shape of the image matter? I can use resnet with images of size (3, size, size)

Comment: @shaft author might have created 3 separate CNN but the network is trained end-to-end all parameters. You can print the total number of trainable parameters. It'll show that all three are shared. Shape of the image matters 3, 256, 256 is for Theano backend 256, 256, 3 is for TF backend.